# How to cache a AVI file using ffMpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am reading a AVI file using ffMpeg.
I want to cache the file into a vector and resuse it later.

This is my code.

```
typedef struct {

    AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx;
    int stream_idx;
    AVStream *video_stream;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
    AVCodec *decoder;
    AVPacket *packet;
    AVFrame *av_frame;
    AVFrame *gl_frame;
    struct SwsContext *conv_ctx;
    unsigned int  frame_tex;

}AppData;

   AppData data;
```

Here i am caching the file to a std::vector

```
std::vector< AVFrame* > cache;    

bool initReadFrame()
{
    do {

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, data.frame_tex);
        int error = av_read_frame(data.fmt_ctx, data.packet);       
        if (error)
        {           
            av_free_packet(data.packet);
            return false;
        }

        if (data.packet->stream_index == data.stream_idx)
        {
            int frame_finished = 0;

            if (avcodec_decode_video2(data.codec_ctx, data.av_frame, &frame_finished,
                data.packet) < 0) {
                av_free_packet(data.packet);
                return false;
            }

            if (frame_finished)
            {               
                if (!data.conv_ctx)
                {
                    data.conv_ctx = sws_getContext(data.codec_ctx->width,
                        data.codec_ctx->height, data.codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                        data.codec_ctx->width, data.codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
                        SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                }
                sws_scale(data.conv_ctx, data.av_frame->data, data.av_frame->linesize, 0,
                    data.codec_ctx->height, data.gl_frame->data, data.gl_frame->linesize);

                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, data.codec_ctx->width,
                    data.codec_ctx->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                    data.gl_frame->data[0]);

                cache.push_back(av_frame_clone(data.gl_frame)); // Pushing AVFrame* to vector

            }
        }
        av_free_packet(data.packet);
    } while (data.packet->stream_index != data.stream_idx);
    return true;
}
```

here i am trying to read the buffer and updating  GL_TEXTURE_2D

```
void playCache()
{

        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, data.codec_ctx->width,
        data.codec_ctx->height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            cache[temp]->data[0]);

        temp++;

}
```

The issue i am facing is that when i try to read the Cached data the application crashes.

Comment: I am not sure but when i read the doc of ```av_frame_clone ``` it says Create a new frame that references the same data as src. if its a reference if the data is destroyed you loose the object and can't access it. Try in the first time to not destroy the ```data.gl_frame``` or use ```av_frame_move_ref``` instead

Comment: @Draykoon D can you please show me where i can use av_frame_move_ref in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing dead reference in your cache.

```
cache.push_back(av_frame_clone(data.gl_frame));
```

the doc says:

> av_frame_clone: Create a new frame that references the same data as src.

When you destroy src, you loose its content and you can't access it in your cache.
You can try to move the ref to your new frame, or to copies its value.

Move:

```
AVFrame* cachedValue;
av_frame_move_ref(cachedValue, data.gl_frame);
cache.push_back(cachedValue);
```

Copy

```
AVFrame *cachedValue= av_frame_alloc();
cachedValue->format = data.gl_frame->format;
cachedValue->width = data.gl_frame->width;
cachedValue->height = data.gl_frame->height;
cachedValue->channels = data.gl_frame->channels;
cachedValue->channel_layout = data.gl_frame->channel_layout;
cachedValue->nb_samples = data.gl_frame->nb_samples;
av_frame_get_buffer(cachedValue, 32);
av_frame_copy(cachedValue, data.gl_frame);
av_frame_copy_props(cachedValue, data.gl_frame);
cache.push_back(cachedValue);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
avformat_network_init();
    initializeAppData();

    // open video
    if (avformat_open_input(&data.fmt_ctx, stdstrPathOfVideo.c_str(), NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        clearAppData();
        return;
    }

    // find stream info
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(data.fmt_ctx, NULL) < 0) {
        clearAppData();
        return;
    }

    // dump debug info
//  av_dump_format(data.fmt_ctx, 0, "D:\\E\\Event\\2019\\AVI_Badges\\Generic\\Generic.avi", 0);


    // find the video stream
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < data.fmt_ctx->nb_streams; ++i)
    {
        if (data.fmt_ctx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            data.stream_idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (data.stream_idx == -1)
    {
        clearAppData();
        return;
    }

    data.video_stream = data.fmt_ctx->streams[data.stream_idx];
    data.codec_ctx = data.video_stream->codec;

    // find the decoder
    data.decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(data.codec_ctx->codec_id);
    if (data.decoder == NULL)
    {
        clearAppData();
        return;
    }

    // open the decoder
    if (avcodec_open2(data.codec_ctx, data.decoder, NULL) < 0)
    {
        clearAppData();
        return;
    }

    // allocate the video frames
    data.av_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    data.gl_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    int size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, data.codec_ctx->width,
        data.codec_ctx->height);
    uint8_t *internal_buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)data.gl_frame, internal_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
        data.codec_ctx->width, data.codec_ctx->height);
    data.packet = (AVPacket *)av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacket));
```